# I got a NaN in loss function of Keras from the first epoch

Tags: python, keras, nan, loss-function

I got a NaN loss from the first epoch. The shape of train_data is (891,13). The shape of train_labels is (891,2).
I create this model for titanic competition in Kaggle.

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf


def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(train_data.shape[1],), kernel_initializer='normal', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                 optimizer='Adam',
                 metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
k = 3
num_val_samples = len(train_data) // k
num_epochs = 100
all_scores = []
for i in range(k):
    print('processing fold #', i)
    #検証データの準備
    val_data = train_data[i * num_val_samples: (i+1) * num_val_samples]
    val_labels = train_labels[i * num_val_samples: (i+1) * num_val_samples]
    #訓練データの準備
    partial_train_data = np.concatenate([train_data[:i * num_val_samples], train_data[(i+1) * num_val_samples:]], axis=0)
    partial_train_labels = np.concatenate([train_labels[:i * num_val_samples], train_labels[(i+1) * num_val_samples:]], axis=0)

model = build_model()
history = model.fit(partial_train_data,
                    partial_train_labels,
                    epochs=num_epochs,
                    batch_size=1,
                   validation_data=(val_data,val_labels))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may comes from your model definition :

Don't use the `Sigmoid` activation with the `categorical_crossentropy` loss:

- Binary problem : Use `Sigmoid` with `binary_crossentropy`
- Multi-class problem : Use `Softmax` with `categorical_crossentropy`

#### EDIT

Few more hints:

- Check your data, maybe you are feeding corrupted value to your network, check for NaN in the dataset
- Try other optimizers
- Try to scale your data, or try to scale it differently
- Try with a bigger batch size

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I can’t solve this problem even by changing activation function from Sigmoid to Softmax.